# Regex to validate custom alphanumeric string

Tags: regex

I need a Regex expression to validate number of years or days or months.

`1d` or `1 d` or `1 day` etc. to parse number of days

Or
`1-y` or `1.5 year` etc. to parse years.
or 
`2 m` , `2 months` etc. for months.

I won't be a combination of different units like 1 year 3 months, so that is not to worry about.

Here is the Regex that I have built so far to parse days.

```
\b([0-9]{1,4}[-.\s](d|day)?)\b
```

The problem is it is also matching numberic values like `555.` , `98.` etc.

What is missing & should it be?

Comment: don't make the group `(d|day)?` optional, remove the question mark.

Comment: can you give some more examples of the source data.

Comment: For days I want to match - 1d or 1-d or 1 d or 60 day
Same for years and months - 1m or 1 m or 1month or 1 month

Basically m,month, y, year , d, day should be acceptable as the unit.
and integer value for day , decimal value for month and year as a value. 
and either a single space or no space or . or - as a seperator

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
\b\d{1,4}(?:\.\d)?(?:-|\s*)(?:d|days?|m|months?|y|years?)\b
```

This allows exactly 1 digit after the optional decimal point. If you want to allow more, you can add a quantifier there.

[DEMO](http://regexr.com/393lu)

Comment: @user3801109 please explain in your question as what do you want to match and what do you won't.

Comment: I forgot to make the decimal part optional. Fixed now.